Servlet gives 404 error when tried to access
I am developing a web app with JSP and Java. I am doing my first Servlet and I have a problem that I don't know how to resolve. I am using Tomcat 8 and I restarted the server.
I have this basic servlet which class is located at: /intranet/WEB-INF/classes/MAN/VehiculosServlet.class:
package MAN;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class VehiculosServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Configuramos el nmero que queremos enviar al JSP
        int numero = 5;

        // Almacenamos el nmero en el atributo de solicitud
        request.setAttribute("numero", numero);

        // Redirigimos a la pgina JSP
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/intranet/mipagina.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}

Then, I have this lines on web.xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>VehiculosServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MAN.VehiculosServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>VehiculosServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VehiculosServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

And then, I have the JSP that is located on /intranet/mipagina.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Llamada al Servlet</title>
<script>
    // Función para hacer una solicitud HTTP GET al servlet y manejar la respuesta
    function obtenerNumero() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/VehiculosServlet', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                // Manejar la respuesta del servlet
                var numero = xhr.responseText;
                // Mostrar el número en la página
                document.getElementById("numero").innerText = numero;
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="obtenerNumero()">
    <h1>Número devuelto por el Servlet:</h1>
    <p>El número es: <span id="numero"></span></p>
</body>
</html>

I tried to change the different routes, but when I access to this direction: https://mypage.com/intranet/VehiculosSevlet, it gives me 404. And when I enter in https://mypage.com/intranet/mipagina.jsp, it loads but the console gives me an 404 error about the Servlet.
Is something wrong in my code? Its the first time that I make a servlet and I am a bit lost about the concepts of dispatcher and how it redirects to the page or how it is called in the JSP.
If I am complicating and there is another form to make a servlet simpler, I will glad to here it

Servlets and JSP together is a Java web application. This is server side Java programming. What is the functionality you want to achieve with the servlet and jsp programs you had written?
